# Can I alternatively use an arrow function in both filters and maps

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hello I just want to raise pretty basic questions here about arrow. Can I alternatively use an arrow function in both filters and maps

Comment: Yes you can, as long as you understand the difference

Comment: I do understand the difference but I was curios about using it alternatively! Many thanks @Jaro